# Post save signal fires before create super user function

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

i have got stuck into some unusual problem where is need to create profiles based on the different user types
eg .super must not have a profile while other users can have the profile

i have my own user model which extends the base user manager

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username=None, email=None, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Must include username')

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            gender='MALE',
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db) 
        print user
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email,  password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username, email and password.
        """

        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        print user, user.is_admin
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

and then using the below signal i create profiles

```
def new_user_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.is_admin:
        print instance , instance.is_admin , not instance.is_admin
        new_profile, is_created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    else:
        pass

post_save.connect(new_user_receiver, sender=MyUser)
```

The problem i am facing right now is this that the above signal gets fired as soon as user is created and the profile is created for the super user as well

Is there a way by which i can avoid creating profiles for superusers?

Thank you.

Comment: hm, don't understand your problem since you 've already answered `if not instance.is_admin:` on your question

Comment: it enters that block even though it shudnt for superuser

Comment: instance.is_admin is false when the superuser is created ..though it shud be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why profile will be created for admin is because you use `create_user` in `create_superuser`. At first an normal user will be saved. Here the profile is created for every one. At twice this user will be modified to admin. You should call this in your `create_superuser` function:

```
 def create_user(self, username=None, email=None, password=None, is_admin=False):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Must include username')

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            gender='MALE',
            is_admin = is_admin,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db) 
        print user
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email,  password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username, email and password.
        """

        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=password,
            is_admin = True,
        )
        return user
```

**OR**

`if instance.is_admin:
      UserProfile.objects.filter(user=instance).delete()`

after `if not instance.is_admin` ... but this way is not elegant

Comment: Why delete the profile....isnt there a turnaround by which i can avoid the creation of profile for the superuser..the point is to not create in the first  place

Comment: TypeError: create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_admin'

Comment: Why is the second way not elegant?

Comment: Every`create_superuser()` fires two Signals to `new_user_receiver` with the same instance, at first as normal user, at twice as superuser. At first a profil is created for the superuser. At twice the created profile should be deleted for the superuser. It is not elegant because you have to check two times.